# R Taking an average of a variable over intervals of another numeric variable

Tags: r, automation, average

How would I go about calculating an average of column 2 for every x interval in column 1, when the number of rows for the intervals are not always equal?

It seems very simple but I'm not sure where to start.

```
df <- data.frame(dist = c(0.06,0.22,0.38,0.44,0.5,0.52,0.6,0.74,0.76,0.88,0.92,0.94,1,1.18,1.26,1.3,1.4,1.48,1.5), 
            value = c(12,54.6,46.6,59.7,65.4,66.4,67,76.5,77.3,94.5,95.5,95,93.7,106.5,112.3,112.4,112.6,114.3,114.2))
```

Let's say I want to know the block average of column 2 when column 1 goes from 0 - 0.5 then 0.5 - 1 and 1 - 1.5 and so on, but if 0 - 0.5 are 5 rows and 0.5 - 1 are 9 rows, what is the best way to do this without having to specify the row numbers?

I have tried searching but perhaps I'm not using the right key words.

Comment: To clarify the topic, I would change the last part of the title to `over intervals of another numeric variable`

Comment: Thank you @SALAR, I have updated the title as per your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate` in `base R`

```
 aggregate(value ~ grp, transform(df, grp = cut(dist, seq(0, 1.5, .5))), mean)
```

-output

```
  grp    value
1 (0,0.5]  47.6600
2 (0.5,1]  83.2375
3 (1,1.5] 112.0500
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I have flagged this as the solution as it gave me the output in the desired format with the most concise code. The answer given by @Maël is perfectly functional using `tapply`, but I prefer the output from `aggregate`. :)

Comment: How would I be able to implement this in a for loop to run over several identically-formatted dataframes? I have tried looping this using column indexes but I end up with an infinite NA loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hydroceanog if you want to use the aggregate, create the formula with `paste` or `reformulate` i.e. `fmla <- reformulate('grp', response = 'value'); aggregate(fmla, transform(df, grp = cut(dist, seq(0, 1.5, .5))), mean)`   You may need to specify how you are looping as the grp, value assumed to be changing here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` to group according to the value of `dist`:

```r
tapply(df$value, cut(df$dist, seq(0, 1.5, .5)), FUN = mean)
# (0,0.5]  (0.5,1]  (1,1.5] 
# 47.6600  83.2375 112.0500
```

Or, if you prefer `dplyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(gp = cut(dist, seq(0, 1.5, .5))) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

#       gp     mean
#1 (0,0.5]  47.6600
#2 (0.5,1]  83.2375
#3 (1,1.5] 112.0500
```

Comment: Thanks @Maël, would be great also add a column of number of observations `(n)` per each group in `dplyr`

Comment: Sure, one can use `n()`

Comment: Thank you @Maël. The `tapply` works but the `dplyr` version returns the average for the entire column in each row. The only thing I have changed is created another df from the pipe, could this be what is wrong?

Comment: Probably. Check that the data is grouped